# Displaying results using chessboard

Tags: chess, chessboard

When displaying results of a game using chessboard, a mysterious Z shows up. In the following code, I would like to display the result as "1-0", but it shows up as "Z1-0."

How can I avoid this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. e4 1-0}
\showboard
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are actually not using chessboard. `\showboard` is a command from skak. The chessboard command to show a board is `\chessboard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the result outside of the `\mainline`, say `\mainline{1. e4} \textbf{[1-0]}`. I think the chessboard has no support for typesetting results.

Comment: that was very easy